# How to trigger an event when at least one round in a for loop is "True"

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a space invader/dodging game in pygame. I have items that you can touch to e.g. increase health. When the sprite touches the health item, I want the background to be green momentarily. 
Below is what I have at the moment. Since I have more than 1 item on the screen at a time, I check for each time using (line 1). You can see that when touching potion, the fillcolor is set to green

The problem is if the sprite is only touching 1 of the 2 items in the screen, the background will be set to black when checking for the second one.

How do I make it so that if at least 1 of the 2 items is being touched, the background becomes green?

EDIT:
I had made the question too vague in fear of making it too long, so here are more details.

`fillcolor` is the variable that sets the background color of the window. There are three types of items that you can touch, and a maximum of 2 items can appear at once, regardless of the type of item.

This might be a bit long, but what is going wrong is:
By using the for loop,  I am checking the 2 items on the screen, and checking if the item you hit is a potion, ammunition or "fever mode"(powerup item). As you can see if it is "potion", your health is increased and if it is "ammo" your ammo count is being increased. For example if there are two items on the screen and you are touching one of them, which is a potion. Then the background becomes green, however in the next round of the for loop when checking the second item, fillcolor instantly becomes black because you are not touching both of the items, only one of them. What is want to do is to make the background green if you are touching one of them, even if the second one is not touched.

```
for e in items:
    ship.checkItemCollision(e, ship)
    if ship.checkItemCollision(e, ship) == 'potion':
        print('potion')
        ship.health += 0.5
        fillcolor = (0, 255, 0)
        touchDatItem = True
    elif ship.checkItemCollision(e, ship) == 'ammo':
        print('ammo')
        ammoCount += 1
        fillcolor = (255, 255, 0)
        touchDatItem = True
    elif ship.checkItemCollision(e, ship) == 'fever':
        print('fever')
        feverMode = True
        fillcolor = (255, 0, 0)
        touchDatItem = True
    elif not touchDatItem:
        fillcolor = black
```

Here's the whole code:

```
import pygame as pg
import time
import random
import math
pg.init()
display_width = 800
display_height = 600

black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
red = (200, 0, 0)
bllue = (0, 0, 255)
green = (0, 200, 0)
bright_red =(255, 0, 20)
bright_green = (0, 255, 0)
yellow = (255,255,0)
dark_yellow = (150, 150, 0)

clock = pg.time.Clock()
potion = pg.image.load('revive.png')
ammo = pg.image.load('ammo.png')
fever = pg.image.load('fever.png')
gameDisplay = pg.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))

pg.display.set_caption('Object Oriented')


class Item:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = [potion, potion, potion,  ammo, ammo,ammo, ammo, ammo, fever, fever, fever,  fever,  fever,  fever,  fever,  fever,  fever,  fever,  fever,  fever,  fever,  ]
        self.images = potion
        self.speed = 3
        self.width = 30
        self.height = 30
        self.x = 30
        self.y = random.randrange(-1000, -300)
    def move(self):
        self.y += self.speed

        if self.y > display_height:
            self.x = random.randrange(0, (display_width - self.width))
            self.y = random.randrange(-5000, -1000)
            self.images = random.choice(self.items)
    def draw(self):

        gameDisplay.blit(self.images, (self.x, self.y))


class Thing:
    def __init__(self):
        self.width = 20
        self.height = 20
        self.x = random.randrange(0, (display_width - self.width))
        self.y = random.randrange(-500, 0)
        self.speedY = 3
        self.speedX = 3
        self.color = bright_red
        self.ratio = random.randrange(-3, 3)

    def move(self, count):
        if self.ratio == 0:
            self.y += self.speedY
        else:
            self.y += self.speedY
##        self.x += random.randint(-5, 5)
            self.x += self.ratio
        if self.y > display_height:
            self.x = random.randrange(0, (display_width - self.width))
            self.y = random.randrange(-500, 0)
            self.ratio = random.randrange(-3, 3)
            return True

    def draw(self):
        pg.draw.rect(gameDisplay, self.color, [self.x, self.y, self.height, self.width])
##    def randomizeX(self):
##        self.x = random.randrange(0, (display_width - self.width))
##    def resetY(self):
##        self.y = 05


##def checkQuit():
##    for event in pg.event.get():
##            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
##                pg.quit()
##                quit()

class Ship:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = display_width / 2
        self.y = display_height / 2
        self.speed = 10
        self.height = 20
        self.width = 20
        self.color = yellow
        self.changeX = 0
        self.changeY = 0
        self.health = 100
##    def move(self, event):
##
##        if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
##            print(event.key)
##            if event.key == pg.K_LEFT:
##                self.change = -(self.speed)
##            if event.key == pg.K_RIGHT:
##                self.change = self.speed
##        if event.type == pg.KEYUP:
##            if event.key == pg.K_LEFT or event.key == pg.K_RIGHT:
##                self.change = 0
##        self.x += self.change
    def draw(self):
        pg.draw.rect(gameDisplay, self.color, [self.x, self.y, self.height, self.width])
    def moveShip(self, event):
        if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
##            print(self.changeY)
##            print(self.changeX)

            if event.key == pg.K_LEFT:
                self.changeX = -(self.speed)
            if event.key == pg.K_RIGHT:
                self.changeX = self.speed
            if event.key == pg.K_UP:
                self.changeY = -(self.speed)
            if event.key == pg.K_DOWN:

                self.changeY = self.speed


        if event.type == pg.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pg.K_LEFT or event.key == pg.K_RIGHT or event.key == pg.K_UP or event.key == pg.K_DOWN:
                self.changeX = 0
                self.changeY = 0
    def testWallCollision(self):
        if self.x > (display_width - self.width) or self.x < 0:
            self.health = self.health/2

    def checkThingCollision(self, t, ship, fillcolor, red, count):
#        if thing_starty < (y + car_height) and y < (thing_starty+thing_height):
        if (t.y - (t.height/2))  < (ship.y + ship.height) and ship.y  < ((t.y - (t.height/2)) + t.height):
            if (self.x > t.x and self.x < (t.x + t.width) or ((self.x + t.width) > t.x and (self.x + t.width) < t.x + t.width)):
                self.health -= 0.5
                t.x = random.randrange(0, (display_width - t.width))
                t.y = random.randrange(-500, 0)
                t.ratio = random.randrange(-10, 10)

    def checkItemCollision(self, e, ship):
        if e.y < (ship.y + ship.height) and ship.y < (e.y + e.height):
            if (self.x > e.x and self.x < (e.x + e.width) or ((self.x + e.width) > e.x and (self.x + e.width) < e.x + e.width)):
                if e.images == potion:
                    return 'potion'
                elif e.images == ammo:
                    return 'ammo'
                elif e.images == fever:
                    return 'fever'


class Bullet:
    def __init__(self, ship):
        self.speed = 20
        self.color = white
        self.x = ship.x + (ship.width / 2)
        self.y = ship.y + (ship.width / 2)
        self.height = 5
        self.width = 5
    def draw(self):
##        print('IN DRAAAAAW')
##        if event.key == pg.K_SPACE:
        pg.draw.rect(gameDisplay, self.color, [self.x, self.y, self.height, self.width])
    def move(self, ship):
        self.y -= self.speed
##        if self.y < 0:
##            self.x = ship.x + (ship.width / 2)
##            self.y = ship.y + (ship.width / 2)
    def checkCollision(self, t, ship, count):
        if t.y < (self.y + self.height) and self.y < (t.y + t.height):
            if (self.x > t.x and self.x < (t.x + t.width) or ((self.x + t.width) > t.x and (self.x + t.width) < t.x + t.width)):
                t.x = random.randrange(0, (display_width - t.width))
                t.y = random.randrange(-500, 0)
                t.ratio = random.randrange(-10, 10)
                self.y = -self.height
                return True


def healthNum(health, color):
    font = pg.font.SysFont(None, 25)
    text = font.render('health:' + str(health) + '/100', True, color)
    gameDisplay.blit(text, (500, 0))

def ammoNum(ammoCount, color):
    font = pg.font.SysFont(None, 25)
    text = font.render('ammo:' + str(ammoCount), True, color)
    gameDisplay.blit(text, (300, 0))

def things_dodged(count):
    font = pg.font.SysFont(None, 25)
    text = font.render('score: ' + str(count), True, white)
    gameDisplay.blit(text, (0, 0))


def main_loop():
    touchDatItem = False
    feverTimer = 0
    gameExit = False
    allItems = [potion, ammo]

    things = []
    ship = Ship()
    bullets = []
    fillcolor = black
    count = 0
    items = []
    ammoCount = 20
    FEVER = False
    LIST = []
    feverMode = False
    for t in range (30):
        things.append(Thing())
    for e in range(2):
        items.append(Item())

    while not gameExit:
        print(fillcolor)
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                pg.quit()
                quit()
            ship.moveShip(event)
            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_SPACE:
##                    FEVER = True
                    if ammoCount > 0:
                        bullets.append(Bullet(ship))
                        if not feverMode:
                            ammoCount -= 1
                    if feverMode:
                        FEVER = True
                    else:
                        FEVER = False
            if event.type == pg.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pg.K_SPACE:
                    FEVER = False
        if FEVER == True:
            feverTimer += 1
            if not feverTimer > 100:
                if ammoCount > 0:
                    bullets.append(Bullet(ship))
            else:
                print('STAAAAAAAAAP')
                FEVER = False
                feverTimer = 0
                feverMode = False

        ship.x += ship.changeX
        ship.y += ship.changeY
        ship.testWallCollision()
        gameDisplay.fill(fillcolor)
        LIST = []
        healthNum(ship.health, white)
        ammoNum(ammoCount, white)
        for t in things:
            ship.checkThingCollision(t, ship, fillcolor, red, count)
            if ship.checkThingCollision(t, ship, fillcolor, red, count) == True:
                print('###########################')
                ship.color = red
            else:
                ship.color = yellow
            t.draw()
            ship.draw()
            t.move(count)
            if t.move(count) == True:
                count+= 1

        for b in bullets:
            b.draw()
            for t in things:
                b.checkCollision(t, ship, count)
                if b.checkCollision(t, ship, count) == True:
                    count += 10

            b.move(ship)

        for e in items:
            ship.checkItemCollision(e, ship)
            if ship.checkItemCollision(e, ship) == 'potion':
                LIST.append('potion')
                print('potion')
                ship.health += 0.5

                touchDatItem = True
            elif ship.checkItemCollision(e, ship) == 'ammo':
                LIST.append('ammo')
                print('ammo')
                ammoCount += 1

                touchDatItem = True
            elif ship.checkItemCollision(e, ship) == 'fever':
                LIST.append('fever')
                print('fever')
                feverMode = True

                touchDatItem = True

            if 'potion' in LIST:
                fillcolor = (0, 255, 0)

            elif 'ammo' in LIST:
                fillcolor = (255, 255, 0)

            elif 'fever' in LIST:
                fillcolor = (255, 0, 0)
            else:
                fillcolor = black

            e.draw()
            e.move()
            print('fillcolor = ' + str(fillcolor))

        if ship.health < 1:
            ship.health = 0
            pg.quit()
            quit()

        things_dodged(count)
        pg.display.update()

        clock.tick(60)

    pg.quit()
    quit()


main_loop()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Your posted code fails in several places for undefined identifiers.  You talk about two items on the screen, but you check for three.  The posted code has four exclusive branches; exactly what is the problem sequence?  Which object is "the sprite"?  This should be a simple matter of setting an appropriate flag and checking after the loop.

Comment: It seems like `fillcolor` is some kind of global variable would be applied to all objects. If you want it to apply only to a particular item, you probably need items to have their own `fillcolor`, but without more code context, we can only guess what you're doing wrong.

Comment: I have updated some more detail

Comment: @KyogoSakai where do you set `touchDatItem`?

Comment: @KyogoSakai please don't post links to your code because they could change or vanish. Just paste your code into the question, but reduce it to a [minimal, runnable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example next time.

Comment: Still too vague of a question, but it looks interesting. Please condense it so we can try it out.

Answer (score 0):

That happens when you invent your own collision detection function instead of using pygame's collision detection methods. ;) Your `checkItemCollision` method is incorrect.

Change this line ...

```
if (self.x > e.x and self.x < (e.x + e.width) or ((self.x + e.width) > e.x and (self.x + e.width) < e.x + e.width)):
```

to this:

```
if (self.x > e.x and self.x < e.x + e.width or self.x + self.width > e.x and self.x + self.width < e.x + e.width):
```

I'm still not 100% sure if everything is correct now. I'd give your objects a [`self.rect`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) attribute and use it for the collision detection instead, e.g.:

```
# In __init__:
self.rect = pg.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)

# Then check if they collide with the `colliderect`  method.
self.rect.colliderect(e.rect)
```

The rect needs to be moved as well when you update the positions.